# How do I change edit/change <p> text html type?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to replace `<p>Coding everybody</p>` into `<p>Hello world</p>` in HTML with JavaScript.
For example, it would change the word "Coding everybody" to "Hello world".

[image]

EDIT: I'm trying to make and apply the script to a website BY USING A JAVASCRIPT APPLYER (TAMPERMONKEY)
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to edit the text of a specific element, or all instances of this text?

Comment: I am trying to edit a specific element (I think)

Comment: @YT_Lazaro In that case, see whoshotdk's answer below.

Comment: Please be clear with your initial question. Adding additional unrelated information about your query later makes existing answers appear incomplete or just wrong! Unfortunately I cannot help you with that particular software, perhaps it is worth asking a new question with 'TamperMonkey' mentioned from the start.

Comment: This is a little bit confusing, can you please give more detail over what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't know where this paragraph is or how to select it then you could select all paragraphs and find the one with the text that you are looking for.

If it's found, update the `textContent` property.

```
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');
const target = Array.from(paragraphs).find(para => para.textContent === 'Coding everybody');
if (target !== null) {
  target.textContent = 'Hello World';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a way of 'selecting' the element you want to change.

You could add an ID;

```
<p id="myParagraph">Coding everybody</p>
```

Then, with Javascript;

```
const element = document.querySelector('#myParagraph');
element.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
```

Comment: How do I add an ID? Do I edit it as html?

Comment: You can add an id by adding the HTML attribute `id="put id here"` to the element.

Comment: If its easiest for you, simply copy my '<p id.....' line and replace your '<p>Coding...' line :)

Comment: But I am using Tampermonkey to launch the javascript and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer to the new question (getting this to work in TamperMonkey).

You could give this a try instead;

```
const element = document.querySelector('.username.goldbar > p');
element.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
```